# REST filter by Created By (Author)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

In SharePoint Online, is it possible to filter a survey list by `Created By`? I've found several posts with similar question but none of the suggested solutions work (i.e. `expand=Author` or `expand=Author/ID`. I'm trying to find out if the current user already voted.

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
    myVote();
 });

function myVote() {
var webAbsUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var currUser = _spPageContextInfo.userEmail;
var tCounter = 0;
var tCount;
var tEMail;

var voteUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Survey')/Items?$\
  filter=Author/EMail eq '" + currUser + "'&$\
  select=Id, Author/EMail&$\
  expand=Author/Id";

var voteAjax = $.ajax({
  url: voteUri,
  async: false,
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  success: function (data) {
    tCount = data.d.results.length;
    if (tCount == 1) {
        console.log ('Current user already voted.');
    } else if (tCount == 0) {
        console.log ('Has not voted.');
    } else {
        console.log ('Something went wrong');
    }
    //Just for test
    if(data.d != undefined) {
      $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
        tId = data.d.results[tCounter].Id;
        tEMail = data.d.results[tCounter].Author.EMail;
        console.log (tEMail);
        tCounter++;
      });
    }
  },
  errors: function(data) { console.log("Failed to load votes"); }
});
}
```

First error is the `tCount` - it should only return 1 but its returning 2 (total # of people responded, mine included).

Second error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EMail' of undefined`.

I also tried filtering by AuthorID, `tCount` also returned 2.

If I don't filter, then the second error goes away and logs each `Author.EMail` in console.

Answer (score 1):

We can use current user Id to pass the $filter in REST API for Author. The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    myVote();
});
function myVote() {
    var webAbsUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var currUser = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var tCounter = 0;
    var tCount;
    var tEMail;

    var voteUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Survey')/Items?$filter=Author eq '" + currUser + "'&$select=Id,Author/EMail&$expand=Author";

    var voteAjax = $.ajax({
        url: voteUri,
        async: false,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            tCount = data.d.results.length;
            if (tCount == 1) {
                console.log ('Current user already voted.');
            } else if (tCount == 0) {
                console.log ('Has not voted.');
            } else {
                console.log ('Something went wrong');
            }
            //Just for test
            if(data.d != undefined) {
                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                    var tId = item.Id;
                    tEMail = item.Author.EMail;
                    console.log (tEMail);
                    tCounter++;
                });
            }
        },
        errors: function(data) { console.log("Failed to load votes"); }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for that to work you need to either expand on the `Email` property of the `Author`, or just expand on the entire `Author` like

```
$expand=Author/Email
```

or

```
$expand=Author
```

but **not**

```
$expand=Author/Id
```

because that then is only returning the ID of the Author user, when what you are trying to get to is the email.